# Adding data to a dB using EF 6.x

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I have 2 entities corresponding to 2 tables in the dB. Name of the 2 tables are: Doc and Users

Each entity has some properties. The relation between Doc and Users is 0 or 1 to many. I am doing something as following:

```
Doc document = new Doc();
...
...
document .Users.Add(new User{Name = "Temp", Info = "Some info.."});
context.AddToDocuments(document);
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, only the entries in Doc table is added in the dB. The User table in the dB is empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: user = new User(...); context.Users.Add(user); document.Users.Add(user);

Comment: does user have a DocumentID  property or something of the sort ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add each entity:

```
Doc document = new Doc();
...
...
User usr = new User() {Name = "Temp", Info = "Some info.."};
context.Users.Add(usr);
document .Users.Add(usr );
context.AddToDocuments(document);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks.. Just that EF 6.x does not have context.Users.Add() , rather it has context.AddToUsers()